# Linking AWS's DynamoDB with Android Java

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run a user login/register activity and send the user data to my DynamoDB
All I want is for a user to enter his/her name and e-mail
The following code is from my 'MainActivity' and my mapper class ('Store.java')

```
    MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager;
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.Dataset;
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.DefaultSyncCallback;
    import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*;
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;

    import java.util.List;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailInput);  //colect e-mail
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordInput);  //colect password
    final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);


    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    //when 'Sign up today!' gets clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, setup1.class);  //takes you from MainActivty
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);                        //to setup1Activity
        }
    });

    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "us-east-2:0f####e#-3e##-####-8##e-de########b0", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
    );

    //Pass your initialized Amazon Cognito credentials provider to the AmazonDynamoDB constructor:
    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

    //Pass your initialized DynamoDB client to the DynamoDBMapper constructor:
    final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

    //create Object


    //always finish with the below statement
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Store userStorage = new Store();
            //call methods created in objects
            userStorage.setEmail("demo@gmail.com");
            userStorage.setName("Adam");
            mapper.save(userStorage);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

```
  STORE.JAVA (Mapper Object)
 import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;

 @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UserStorage")
 public class Store {
  private String email;
  private String name;

@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "Email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "Name")
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Whenever I run my code, the mainActivity fails to launch on a phone/emulator and none of the data gets transmitted to my DB
Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Are there no errors being logged?

Comment: No errors are logged, the program seems to run smoothly 
But it's not giving me the output I need

Comment: It runs smoothly but "the mainActivity fails to launch"?